# Can't login to wp-admin. ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Tags: wordpress

I can't login to my wordpress admin. I am getting a “The web page isn’t working

.... redirected you too many times” message.

I tried removing .htaccess file and replaced default .htacess file but it's still not working.

Can anyone help me?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Hi, Had you found any solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like some plugin is causing this.

In the first instance, login to the site via FTP, rename the plugins folder (wp-content/plugins) and check. If that works, rename the plugins folder back, then keep renaming each folder inside the plugins folder one by one and then checking, until you identify the offending plugin. Once you find out the culprit, make sure that its folder remains renamed, revert all the other folder names back to original and login. (After that, either uninstall and reinstall the bad plugin or find a suitable alternative for it.)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'], 'https') !== false)
    $_SERVER['HTTPS']='on';
else
    $_SERVER['HTTPS']='off';
```